# Number of all possible sub-trees of m nodes of a given k-regular tree of n nodes.

Tags: graph-theory

I have a k-regular tree of *n* nodes rooted at *u* and I wish to find all its possible sub-trees of *m* nodes, again rooted at *u*. It will be of immense help. Thank you.

Comment: You're talking about labeled subtrees, not isomorphism classes, right?

Comment: Precisely. Just labeled sub-trees.

Answer (score 1):

I think we have to be satisfied with a recursive formula.  Let $T$ be a $k$-regular tree rooted at $u$ and let $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_k$ be the children of $u$.  For $n=1,2,\dots,k$ let $T_k$ be the subtree rooted at $u_n$ containing u_n and all of its descendants, together with the edge $uu_n.$  I include the edge $uu_n$ so that $T_n$ will be $k$-regular.  The subtrees of $T_n$ rooted at $u_n$ that contain uu_n are in one-to-one correspondence with with the subtrees that don't contain it, so we can include half the subtrees of $T_n$ in constructing subtrees of $T$.  Also, we may not include $u_n$ at all.

Let $f_k$ be the function that counts the labeled subtrees rooted at $u$.  Then the foregoing considerations show $$f(T)=
\cases{1,&height($T$)=0\\
\prod_{n=1}^k(1+f(T_n)/2),&otherwise}$$